# DOMPDF doesn't fill the document with the background-url as defined in CSS

Tags: php, html, css, dompdf

When PDF file is generated with DOMPDF not all the entire page is filled with the background image property[image] and also some part of the text is outside from of the background image
[image] 
But everything else is fine.SO what i would like is to fill every white space with the given background image.

```
body{background-image:url('myfile.png')}
```